# I can't stop scroll in iPhone's

Tags: scroll

I gave this
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
document.body.style.touchAction = "none";

For certain div to stop when it's in the full viewport of the device it's working fine in every device except iPhones.

I want to stop scroll for 2 sec in iPhones